# Root of hair moves with hair dynamic

Tags: particles, physics, hair

I just finished to create all particles of my character's hair and comb it. After baking the particle dynamics, when I play the animation the hair's roots are moving even though they are supposed to be fixed to the head. Is there a parameter that can be the cause of that issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I found it, the solution was to go to "Particle edit" mode, select "particule select mode: path, then Select -> Roots and finally Particles -> Weight set with the strenght set to 1 in the tool panel.